# Why is statutory rape "strict liability"?

Tags: law

I've heard that statutory rape, that is, sex with girls under 18 works under strict liability principle.

Why?

Is this even true?

Even murder, that obviously cause far more damage, has 1st degree, 2nd degree, and so on.

Why statutory rape is made strict liability?

Some possible case why strict liability may not be a good idea:

There are rumors that Epstein isn't really a pedophile. If he really wants 14 years old girl he can easily go to countries where it's legal.

What he really did is blackmailing politicians. Politician, say Clinton or Trump, have sex with the girl. Then the girl turns out to be say 16.

Without strict liability, this scam won't work. The guy simply says I didn't know she's 16. With strict liability, underage girls can conspire to blackmail guys.

Comment: This should be asked in the Laws stack exchange. Also, a country needs to be specified.

Comment: What the law is should be in laws stackexchange. Why the laws are the way it is should be in politic

Comment: This could fit in Law, but it also fits in Politics.  Some questions are on-topic in more than one SE.

Comment: I wonder if law enforcement is in politic too? For example, why federal government don't pursue marijuana. That seems like much political questions than laws

Comment: This question mischaracterizes the crime of statutory rape.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question that I'm answering is why should statutory rape laws be strict liability?  I'm not trying to answer the legal question of whether they might or might not be in a particular case or even jurisdiction.

[Strict liability](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/strict_liability) means that intent does not matter.  So in the specific case of statutory rape, the court does not have to:

1. Determine if the child consented.
2. Weigh conflicting testimony about whether the child consented.

The court can simply determine if the adult and child participated in a sex act.  This is simpler and easier to prove.  Also, it steps around coercion.  For example, giving a child a lollipop in exchange for oral sex is illegal under a strict liability standard.

> I've heard that statutory rape, that is, sex with girls under 18 works under strict liability principle.

Often [statutory rape](https://www.cga.ct.gov/2003/olrdata/jud/rpt/2003-R-0376.htm) is defined as sex with a child under a certain age.  Sex under eighteen but above the statutory rape age is a similar but different crime and may not be held to a strict liability standard.  The exact age may differ between jurisdictions.  In some jurisdictions (Arizona) it might even be eighteen.  But in many, there are at least two ages.

The general rule is that such children cannot consent to sex, as they don't really understand what is being asked of them.

> Even murder, that obviously cause far more damage, has 1st degree, 2nd degree, and so on

It's not obvious to me that murder causes more damage.  For example, [Jerry Sandusky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jerry_Sandusky) was probably statutorily raped as a child.  The result being that he later statutorily raped multiple children, including his own son who also went on to statutorily rape yet more children.  There is a reasonable argument that this causes more damage.

Beyond this, the differing degrees of murder and manslaughter are about intent and planning.  Under a strict liability standard, self defense would be as illegal as a deliberate, planned murder.

With statutory rape, there is no accidental or self-defense version.  It is always a deliberate act and it is clearly the responsibility of the adult to avoid the occurrence of the act.  Thus the adult is strictly liable.

Comment: In the United States, the age of consent is usually 16.  It often erroneously thought to be 18 but that has more to do with the fact that it is 18 in California and California is where all the porn gets made (not to mention all the crime TV shows).  16 is much closer to Common Law age of consent used in England and many other Common Law settings.  Additionally, most age of consent laws have "Romeo and Juliette" clauses where the strict liability is relaxed if both parties are close in age, but one is over the statute while the other isn't (a 16 year old boyfriend and his 15 year old girlfriend

Comment: interesting. 16 is low enough. Lower than Indonesians' age of consent